# Finding number of sub strings between two giving chars

Tags: java, string

I need for my homework to write method that get two parameters, string and char, and it needs to return the number of strings that start with that char and end with that char.

**Example:**
For the string `"abcbcabcacab"` and the char 'c', the method will return 6.
(the sub strings are `"cbc", "cabc", "cac", "cbcabc", "cabcac", "cbcabcac"`)

It needs to be as effectiveness as possible, and the only two method that I can use is `charAt()` and `length()`.This is hard as hell and after 3 hours of trying, I'm asking you guys if there is someone who cal solve this or at least show me some clue.

Comment: Let us see your code so far.

Comment: I wrote everything on paper so far since I'm still trying to get the idea of how to approach this.

Comment: Code on paper is never a good idea because it doesn't come with a compiler. Give it an honest effort in an IDE.

Comment: @Avishay28 no one will do your homework here. please write your solution, post it here and people will try to give you better directions or suggest improvements if needed.

Comment: I wrote down some pseudo code but nothing really practical, I'm not asking you to do the homework for me but at least give me some clue of general structure of the code..

Comment: @Avishay28 'cbc' is invalid sub-string, as it does not contain c in the middle

Comment: @Lashane right it doesn't have to contain that char at the middle, I edit the post.

Comment: @Avishay28 what if input string is `cc` - how many substrings are here 0 or 1?

Comment: 1, since it start with c and end with c (it doesn't have to contain something in the in-between)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious solution is to check every symbol in input string and if equals to specified char, then try to find all possible substrings, starting from this point, like this:

```
long cnt = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < (s.length() - 1); i++)
    if (s.charAt(i) == c)
        for (int j = (i + 1); j < s.length(); j++)
            if (s.charAt(j) == c)
                cnt++;
return cnt;
```

this solution has complexity O(N^2)

but, number of substrings actually determined by number of occurrences of char in string, which appeared to be [Triangular number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number)

So, optimized O(N) solution is:

```
long cnt = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    if (s.charAt(i) == c)
        cnt++;
return (cnt * (cnt + 1)) >>> 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you explain me what the ">>> 1" mean?

Comment: @Avishay28 is faster division by 2, so `>>>1` can be replaced with `/2`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest anwser is that you should use a loop.

Loop through the strings. Check if the current string starts with the given char and ends with the given char. If it doesn't just jump to the next one. if it does just loop with a counter from 1 to length minus the second last char.

You will reduce time by kicking out invalid string and you will be checking 2 chars less EVERY string ;)
I guess that's a quite fast way.

Example

```
// String definition bla String[] myArray
int count = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length(); i++) {

  if(myArray[i].charAt(0) == givenChar && myArray[i].charAt(myArray.length()-1)) {

    for(int j = 1; j < myArray.length()-2;j++) {

      if(myArray[i].charAt(j) == givenChar) 
        count ++;

    }
  }
}
```

That's the rough idea.

I am checking if the given String starts and ends with the givenChar.
If it does im iterating through the string checking for the givenChar again.
If it does exist i am counting 1 up.

I hope that might help your out ;)

Have a nice day!

Comment: Thanks. What's "myArray[]"? Is that the string given?

Comment: the function could look something like that

public (static) int myFunction(String[] myArray,char givenChar)

If the function needs to be static you could add the tag, otherwise remove.

myArray should contain the strings you want to check like the ones you listed in your original post.

Comment: But the function should get String and char, not array. Why to put it in array? Only one string given..

Comment: AH i am sorry, i read another post and i kinda messed it up there xD.
But Lashane found a good solution